# Getting asp.net user control to emit SCRIPT block only once if needed

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, webforms, user-controls

I'm seeking advice on how to best encapsulate this HTML markup and behavior for extensive reuse.

I've developed a working version of some "context sensitive" help on a given .aspx page that uses the qTip2 plugin for jQuery ("squeezed up" here for completeness for the question):

```
$('a.myMore[title]').qtip({
    content: {  title: { button: true } }
    , style: { classes: 'qtip-youtube myCustomClass' }
    , position: { target: 'mouse',  adjust: { x: 5, y: 5} }
    , show: { effect: function() {  $(this).fadeTo(500, 1); } }
    , events:{hide:function(event, api) {if (event.originalEvent.type !== 'click') return false;}}
});
```

Here is a sample of the the markup operated upon by the plugin above that I'd like to encapsulate:

```
<a class="myMore" href="#" title='Text here will be displayed by a jQuery plugin called qTip2'>
   <img src='../images/icon/info1.png' alt='?' />
</a>
```

This is in an older environment of Visual Studio 2008 webforms using VB.Net. One thread on SO expressed my need very well - see [MVC3 Razor views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289090/how-to-encapsulate-a-reusable-control-for-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-views) - but the only encapsulation approach I can think of is writing an ASP.Net web user control (.ascx) to dump out the HTML I need. I envision being able to sprinkle something like this throughout my .aspx pages:

```
<qTipH:qTipHelper Title="Here is some content for the qTip." runat="server" />
```

**Am I on the right track given the "old-ish" environment in which I have to work?**

I started in on writing this control and immediately noticed there is no title attribute for any of these server controls - `<asp:HyperLink nor <asp:ImageButton nor <asp:LinkButton`. I don't think the code-behind of the user control can inject the title attribute text into a standard HTML `<a>` tag.

I think I know what I need rendered but I'm looking for advice on the best approach. Thanks.

**EDIT - UPDATE:**

So here is my .ascx file I came up with:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" 
  CodeBehind="qTipHelper.ascx.vb"
  Inherits="myProjectName.qTipHelper" %>

<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" CssClass="myMore"></asp:HyperLink>
```

I discovered that any "missing" attributes like "title" can be handled by the following code-behind which adds to the **Attributes** collection of the control:

```
Public Partial Class qTipHelper
Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
Public Title As String = Nothing
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
If Title Is Nothing OrElse Title = "" Then
        Visible = False
Else
    Dim encodedTitle As String = Server.HtmlEncode(Title)
    HyperLink1.Attributes.Add("title", encodedTitle)
    HyperLink1.Attributes.Add("href", "#")
    HyperLink1.ImageUrl = "../images/icon/info1.png"
End If
End Sub
End Class
```

On my invoking page(s), I added this:

```
<%@ Register  TagPrefix="qTip" TagName="qTipHelper" Src="~/UserControls/qTipHelper.ascx" %>
```

and then to spit out the HTML, I added this:

```
<qTip:qTipHelper runat="server" title="grist for the mill courtesy of qTip" >
        </qTip:qTipHelper>
```

Is there a coding technique that could be added to the user control that would emit ***one*** Javascript script block at the bottom of the page (assuming that one or more tags for qTipHelper were present in the HTML above)?

Answer (score 0):

In retrospect, this is weird question (I think because I never had to do anything like this before)...

Anyway, I simply collected all my current uses of qtip in a single Javascript file which I reference at the bottom of each .aspx page that uses it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/js/qTipCode.js") %>"></script>
```

So, this boils down to:

```
1. writing a single user control 
2. registering the user control on .aspx content pages that will need it
3. sprinkling the .aspx content page with the user control tag whereever it is needed
4. adding the script tag to point to the qtip Javascript file 
5. ensuring that the selectors in the jQuery "match up" with the HTML markup on the page
```

I hope this helps someone else. I have learned alot about new stuff trying this.